# Configure Different Node MySQL connections for different environments

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I have 3 different MySQL database connections depending the environment (local, dev and live).

Using node-mysql, how do I serve the correct connection details or detect the environment being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process.env.NODE_ENV variable is where the value is stored.

You can do something like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production')
```

OR this is built into the app.configure function

```
app.configure('development', function(){

});

app.configure('production', function(){

...
});
```

SETTING THE VARIABLE FROM COMMAND LINE

LINUX:

```
$ echo export NODE_ENV=production >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

WINDOWS:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
setx NODE_ENV production
```

Comment: Local environment is windows. Dev and production are Linux.

Comment: edited answer. the linux example saves it to the bash profile so will exist after reboot.  you could just "export NODE_ENV=production"  on windows set temporarily sets it and setx is supposed to save it as an environmental variable.